# is it Possible to Use Raspberry PI Bs 26 GPIO pins to output VGA Display?

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi

I am doing a project and I want to play a video in a separate single monitor using **Java** or **C++**.

If my program somehow crashes I want the monitor to be completely black instead of showing OS (I Do not need two monitors , I only want one to be used by my program).

- Is possible to use **GPIO** to produce a **VGA** output using **Java**??

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid this isn't possible:

Gert van Loo (one of the Raspberry Pi Foundation’s earliest volunteers) created an [adapter](https://github.com/fenlogic/vga666) to control a VGA screen with the GPIO pins. In the FAQ [documentation](https://github.com/fenlogic/vga666/blob/master/documents/vga_manual.pdf?raw=true) of the adapter, the author states that it can't work with models A and B because they don't have the appropriate pins needed to handle a VGA signal.

If an other way to do it exists, I don't know it.